# Dynamic text causing gap at the bottom of webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and there's this mysterious 16px gap at the bottom of my webpage. After some tedious trouble shooting  I found the culprit seemed to be one of the elements on the page that was generating post titles.

I removed the titles from the page and the gap disappeared, I replaced it with static text and the gap didn't come back. It only appears whenever I use the dynamic titles.

I've tried various different wordpress functions that generate text and they all seem to produce the same sized gap.

I find it odd that it only happens with dynamic content and not static.

**EDIT** For some reason changing the google font fixed it... I don't even know.

This is the offending block:

```
<div class="col-nsWrapper">
    <div class="col-newStory">
        <div class="col-nsImage">
            <?php 
            $attachment_id = get_field('images');
            $alt_text = get_the_title();
            $size = "home-thumb"; 
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h3><?php the_time('M j'); ?></h3>
            <h2><?php $title = get_field('short_title');
            echo $title;
             ?>
            </h2>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what else to give you as it seems it could be a various number of reasons this might be happening. If you want to see something more specific just ask.

Comment: a online demo would be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whatever header its generating may have padding or margin attached to it, - and you may have selected a different tag with your static text?